# Why is Html.DropDownList() producing <select name="original_name.name"> instead of just <select name="name">?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods

I have an editor template whose job is to take a `SelectList` as its model and build a `select` element in html using the `Html.DropDownList()` helper extension.

I'm trying to assign the `name` attribute for the `select` based on a `ModelMetadata` property. (Reason: on post-back, I need to bind to an object that has a different property name for this item than the ViewModel used to populate the form.)

The problem I'm running into is that `DropDownList()` is *appending* the name I'm providing instead of *replacing* it, so I end up with names like `categories.category` instead of `category`.

Here is some code for you to look at...

**SelectList.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>" %>
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    (string)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["PropertyName"], Model) %>
```

**Resulting HTML**

```
<select id="SkillLevels_SkillLevel" name="SkillLevels.SkillLevel">
    <option value="1">High</option>
    <option value="2">Med</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Low</option>
</select>
```

**Expected HTML**

```
<select id="SkillLevels_SkillLevel" name="SkillLevel">
    <option value="1">High</option>
    <option value="2">Med</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Low</option>
</select>
```

**Also tried**

```
<%= Html.Encode((string)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["PropertyName"])%>
```

...which resulted in "SkillLevel" (not "SkillLevels.SkillLevel"), proving that the data stored in metadata is correct.

and

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    (string)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["PropertyName"], Model,
    new { name = (string)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["PropertyName"] }) %>
```

...which still resulted in `<select name=SkillLevels.Skilllevel>`.

**Questions**

What's going on here? Why does it append the name instead of just using it? Can you suggest a good workaround?

**Update:**

I ended up writing a helper extension that literally does a find/replace on the html text:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BindableDropDownListForModel(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var propertyName = (string)helper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["PropertyName"];
    var compositeName = helper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName + "." + propertyName;
    var rawHtml = helper.DropDownList(propertyName, (SelectList)helper.ViewData.Model);
    var bindableHtml = rawHtml.ToString().Replace(compositeName, propertyName);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(bindableHtml);
}
```

**>>>** I'd still like to understand why this workaround is necessary. Why does the `select` element's get assigned a composite name rather than the exact name I provide?

Comment: Yes, this is annoying.  DropDown support and Templating are two things that could really be improved in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with the MVC drop down - it just does not act right. So, I just roll my own html with a foreach on my model data. That may not be an acceptable workaround for you but MVC is flexible on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not sure if this is totally safe and wont break anything.
But I faced the exact same situation. However, once i set 
 `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = String.Empty` ,
the problem went away. This behavior seems to be by design inside of custom templates - take a look at `ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName` for example.